# Cannot resolve errror message - Dog() takes no arguments

Tags: python

I am doing the Python crash course section on classes and I am getting an error message which says "Dog () takes no arguments"

From similar examples people point out that there needs to be two underscores before and after of the "init".  I do have that, and I still get an error message.  Does anyone have any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

```
class Dog:
    """ A simple attempt to model a dog"""

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        '''Initiatize the name and age attributes'''
        self.name = name 
        self.age = age
    
    def sit(self):
        '''Simulate a dog sitting in response to a command'''
        print(f"{self.name} is now sitting")
    
    def roll_over(self):
        '''Simulate a rolling in response to a commmand '''
        print(f"{self.name} rolled over!")
    
my_dog = Dog("Willie", 6)

print(f"My dog's name is {my_dog.name}")

print(f"My dog's age is {my_dog.age} years old")
```

Comment: The only problem in your code seems to be the indentation (primordial in python), I made an edit suggest

Comment: Works for me in Python 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

The methods need to be indented as well.

The way you've written your code now, Python doesn't consider the functions you've defined methods of the `Dog` class.